# Класс не существует в пространстве имен

Tags: wpf, xaml

Возникает ошибка в примере из книги Макдональда "WPF в .NET 4.0":

[image: Ошибка]

Сам пример:

Например, предположим, что есть класс, не имеющий конструктора без аргументов:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }    
}
```

Создать его экземпляр в XAML 2009 можно следующим образом:

```
<local:Person>
   <х:Arguments>
      <x:String>Joe</x:String>
      <x:String>McDowell</x:String>
   </х:Arguments>
</local:Person>
```

Мой код:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Разметка:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        Width="300"  Height="300">
    <Grid>
        <local:Person> <!--Ошибка возникает здесь-->

        </local:Person>    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Grid` содержит коллекцию `UIElement`'ов(`UIElementCollection`) в качестве своих «детей», Вы же передаёте класс `Person` в качестве «сына» `Grid`, о чём Вам и сообщает студия. Создавайте Ваш `Person` в ресурсах, а не как «сына» `Grid`.

---

Ваш вопрос получается интереснее, чем я думал. Вы не можете сделать то, что хотите и причиной этому является то, что Вы используется синтаксис XAML 2009, который поддерживает создание объектов с параметрами. Но, по какой-то неведомой причине, [WPF не поддерживает XAML 2009](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792007.aspx#xaml_2009_support_in_wpf_and_visual_studio). А это значит, что Вы можете создавать только объекты без параметров.
Выглядеть это будет как-то так:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Person x:Key="MeTheKey"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Эти строчки нужно поместить внутри `Window`(на том же уровен, что у Вас `Grid`)

Comment: Чтобы я не делал постоянно сыпятся различные ошибки. Можете привести готовый код разметки?

Comment: @maxwell, обновил ответ.