# Динамически создавать элементы управления (TextBox'ы) в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый вечер.
Каким образом можно динамически добавлять в `UcerCntrol` элементы управления (`TextBox'ы`)? К примеру есть два объекта `Line` `Circle`

```
public class Line:IObjects
{
 private string _nameObject;
 public Point StartPoint(){get;set;}
 public Point EndPoint(){get;set;}

 public string NameObject{{return "Line";}{_nameObject = value;}}
}

public class Circle:IObjects
{
 private string _nameObject;
 public Point CenterPoint(){get;set;}
 public string NameObject{{return "Line";}{_nameObject = value;}}
}

interface IObject
{
string NameObject{get;set;}
}
```

Когда я получаю объекты интерфейса во View, необходимо отобразить параметры координат, т.к. в `Line` используется два параметра, а в `Circle` один то определяем сколько `TextBox'ов` необходимо отобразить для изменения параметров каждого объекта. Создать предварительно `TextBox'ы` в `UC` не логично, потому что при необходимости мы должны уметь создавать необходимое количество элементов в зависимости от редактируемого объекта.

Comment: А, причём здесь MVVM?

Comment: @Streletz планируется использовать динамически добавленные элементы с данным патерном, т.е. из `ViewModel` передаем данные во `View`, но их необходимо правильно отразить, то есть есть несколько вариантов (приходят координаты, к примеру координаты линии (координаты начала и окончания линии) и круга (координаты центра)) но не красиво делать два `TextBox` для круга, вариант изменять видимость то же не подходит не продуктивно вдруг надо будет добавить многогранник n-граний.

Comment: По вашему описанию абсолютно не ясно, что вы хотите. переформулируйте  вопрос

Comment: просто задавайте точки в массиве, а не по одному свойству

Comment: @FoggyFinder сам факт хранения данных в двумерном массиве не решит проблему с изменением их из View пользователем, хотелось бы реализовать динамически создание элементов (к примеру TextBox)

Comment: @KJfe так ведь и будет динамическое количество, в зависимости от элементов в массиве. Хотя не уверен, что понял почему в двумерном

Comment: @FoggyFinder у меня получается хранятся координаты по (x,y) начальной точки и конечной для линии, так же есть круг с координатами центра (x,y). Так же надо предполагается что в дальнейшем добавятся другие фигуры, для этого просто добавится новый класс с наследуемым интерфейсом. Вопрос в том как добавить элементы `TextBox'a` в WPF не в ручную прописывая в XAML и делая привязку (Binding) а динамически от определенных критерев.

Comment: @FoggyFinder если использовать массив то его в принципе можно запихать в DataGrid и он отобразит все точки, но интересно можно ли как то для каждой координаты добавить `TextBox`

Comment: Вам бы для начала изучить следующие понятия и для чего они используются: `ObservableCollection`, `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `ItemsControl` c `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`. Первой пары ссылок в гугле хватит. По сути: 1) связать оба ваших класса в новом классе LineAndCircle. 2) Создать `ObservableCollection<LineAndCircle>`. 3) В интерфейсе создать `ItemControl` с нужным вам `ItemTemplate`. 4) Привязать `ItemSource` вашего `ItemControl` к `ObservableCollection<LineAndCircle>`

Comment: @John зачем мне связывать эти два класса, если я добавлю туда тысячу элементов фигур (многоугольник с 6 сторонами, треугольники, и всякая лажа, а вдруг еще добавятся и трехмерные фигуры, ломаные), я что их все буду связывать, бред, для этого у меня существует интерфейс, который я добавляю в коллекцию, затем получаю эти параметры из нее.

Comment: @John  А на счет ItemControl сейчас почитаю вроде может и помочь.

Comment: @KJfe: А можно скетч того, как это должно выглядеть?

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, если вы хотите показывать список объектов, для этого нужно и правда использовать `ItemsControl` и привязывать список к `ItemsSource`.

Обычно все объекты одинаковые, и тогда для отображения объекта подходит `ItemTemplate`. ([Тут пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701187/10105).) Но если ваш список разнородный, такой подход не пройдёт. Есть несколько разных путей решения. Можно использовать `ItemTemplateSelector`. Но если у объектов разные типы, то подойдёт такое простое решение:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding тут-имя-вашей-коллекции}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Line}">
            <!-- тут шаблон для отображения линии -->
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Circle}">
            <!-- тут шаблон для отображения окружности -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Вот пример для `DataContext = new object[] { 1, 2, "три", 4, "пять" }`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='String {0}'}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='Int {0}'}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Результат:

[image: вышел кролик погулять]

---

Если вам нужно обработать объекты разного типа в «редакторе», можно использовать ту же технику, но с `ContentPresenter`'ом:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentObject}">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Line}">
            <!-- тут шаблон для редактирования линии -->
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Circle}">
            <!-- тут шаблон для редактирования окружности -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: @VledD Это конечно хорошо, но меня интересовал вопрос как организовать изменение данных для различных объектов, то есть при выборе объекта, открывалось бы поле где оно динамически заполнялось в зависимости от типа объекта и возможно было бы изменить данные.

Comment: @KJfe: Дописал.

Comment: Вопрос а каким образом можно добавить переменную (vm) для моих объектов, или как то в ресуры надо запихать?

Comment: @KJfe: Эээ, в какие-такие ресурсы? View не имеет права задавать себе VM. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/10105

Comment: На счет этого я знаю, я просто не могу понять vm это ссылка на ViewModel?

Comment: @KJfe: Ну да. Но меня смущает слово «ссылка» — вы ведь не говорите про строковую переменную «ссылка на строку»?

Comment: Не я имел ввиду что View использует DataContext=экземпляр класса ViewModel, как то так

Comment: @KJfe: Что означает «использует»? Вы хотите сказать, что View _устанавливает себе_ `DataContext`? Нет, это плохой подход.

Comment: Нет, у меня есть ViewModelMain со свойством FirstVM{get;set;} для FirstUC. А в MainView у меня <ucerControl:FirstUC DataContext="{ Binding FirstVm}"/> как то так

Comment: @KJfe: А, вот это правильный подход. Тогда непонятно, в чём ваш вопрос.

Comment: @KJfe: А, кажется понял. Вы про `vm:`? Нет, это не переменная, это namespace. Вы ж должны как-то сослаться на namespace, в котором определены ваши классы `Circle` и `Line`?

Comment: Вот я как раз про это, тоесть я должен записать namespace Model'и так как у меня классы там определены и наследуют интерфейс.

Comment: @KJfe: Ну есть же стандартный метод подключать неймспейсы: `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Program.Namespace1.Namespace2"`. Вот тут пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576225/10105